# Vue mutation change instance (MyArray to Array)

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I'm extending builtIn **Array** with my class **MyArray**
When i try to store MyArr to Vuex, I loose instance, and get bultIn Array

What's wrong?

```js
class MyArray extends Array{/*some methods*/}

const state = {
  arr: new ModuleOperationArray(),
}

const mutations = {
  setArr: (state) => {
   console.log(state.arr instanceof MyArray); //false -- WHY?

   let arr = new MyArray();
   console.log(arr instanceof MyArray); //true -- expectedly

   state.arr = arr;
   console.log(state.arr instanceof MyArray); //false -- WHY?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make arrays reactive Vue needs to patch various methods such as `push` and `pop` with its own versions. These work just the same as the originals while triggering the reactivity system.

To achieve this patching quickly Vue switches out the prototype of the Array to its own extended version. See:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/9fbd416635eb3d7b32cd73b7c29f8377003c4dc8/src/core/observer/index.js#L49

The specifics vary depending on browser support.

The `instanceof` operator determines its value based on the prototype chain. Once Vue has made the switch your array will no longer have `MyArray` in its prototype chain.

Comment: Question was about why Vue switch array. Not about reactivity, pop and push

Comment: @user1272025 My answer explains why Vue switches the array.